# How to have multiple relationships between two entities with two way navigation properties (Code-First)?

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

As you can see in the code below I have two tables having one **One-to-Many** and one **Many-to-Many** relationships with each other. This code seems wrong since I won't be able to navigate to Meeting entities from Person entities. I don't know the jargon but I'll tell you in english.

You know each person have attended many meetings
You know each person have created many meetings
You know each meeting has many attendees
You know each meeting has one creator

When we talk about a meeting, you can tell the creator using the foreign key "Creator_ID"
When we talk about a meeting, you can tell who were the attendees using the intermediate mapping table

When we talk about a person you can tell the meetings that this person attended using the intermediate mapping table

But

When we talk about a person to tell the meetings that this person have created you should go through all the meetings and check their foreign key "Creator_ID"

I know this is how DBMS works. But since I am working with Entity Framework, I want to be able to use

```
meetings = thisPerson.meetingsCreated;



public class Person
    {

        public int ID {get; set;}
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Meeting> meetingsAttended { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Meeting> meetingsCreated { get; set; }          
    }

public class Meeting
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        string Title { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Creatator_ID")]
        public virtual Person createdBy { get; set; }
        public virtual ObservableCollection<Person> Attendees { get; set; }          
    }
```

Should I implement a method in Person class which goes through all the meetings and returns the meetings created by this Person? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you should have some configuration instructions like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

    modelBuilder.Entity<Meeting>().HasResquired(m => m.CreatedBy).WithMany(p => p.meetingCreated);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Meeting>().HasMany(m => m.Attendees).WithMany(p => p.meetingAttended);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also how can I read all the related meetings for a person at once from db?  Like a property "relatedMeetings" of people class which includes all meetings that Person attended or created?